# Keyboard shortcut for Flicker free Dimming in My-Asus app in Asus OLED Laptops

Tags: display, keyboard-shortcuts, asus-laptop, brightness, oled

When I lower my laptop's brightness more then 60% in ASUS OLED laptop, my display starts flickering and my eyes strains a lot. Thankfully Asus provides flicker free dimming technology inside My-Asus app.

This helps to reduce brightness without flicker. I generally keep at 30% (i.e., flicker free dimming brightness) and my laptops brightness at 100%. But I need to open my asus app frequently to change brightness according to environment. I was curious to know if there is a way to set keyboard shortcut to quickly lower brightness that uses flicker free dimming technology inside My-Asus app.

*I keep my laptop's brightness at 100% (provided by windows) and always use flicker free dimming to dim/brighten my laptop display from inside asus app.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an older thread, but: I've created a program to do that here: https://github.com/NH5pml30/for-asus-bright-ctrl. You can try using it and see if it works! Installation procedure and usage is described there in the README

Comment: Thankyou so much broo.. You forgot your 

Answer (score 0):

You may change the display brightness in Windows with this PowerShell command:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,DESIRED_BRIGHTNESS_LEVEL)
```

Replace `DESIRED_BRIGHTNESS_LEVEL` with the percent level,
for example `30` or `100`.

If you wish to include it inside a batch file (`.bat`), use :

```
powershell (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,DESIRED_BRIGHTNESS_LEVEL)
```

You may create two scripts on your desktop for the two brightness levels
and assign each a keyboard shortcut, to change the brightness with ease.

Comment: Isn't the 'default' windows version causing the flickering, and there's some 'non standard' method asus is using? - as such the powershell command isn't really going to help

Comment: If this doesn't work for ASUS, so only the My-Asus app can do that, perhaps an AutoHotKey macro can help. I can't help then, because I'm not on ASUS.

Comment: Well that's what I was going to point out.

Comment: @harrymc This command changes the windows brightness which causes flickers. Asus provides this option in MyAsus app.  https://ibb.co/sFCSy5s

Comment: I need to set keyboard shortcut that changes this slider instead of changing windows brightness slider.

Comment: (1) What is the display refresh rate ? A low rate is one of the reasons for flicker. (2) Another cause is Hardware acceleration, disabled in *Settings > System > Display > Graphics settings*.